# How do you include custom CSS in the Facebook Like Box?

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-likebox

I know this question is being asked time and time again, but with Facebook constantly updating it's code and adding / taking out features it's impossible to keep track of.

Can anyone give me an example of the current syntax to include an external CSS file? I need to create custom styling for an advertisement that I am building.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot style the Like Box [beyond what FB will allow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/).  They are very protective of their branding.

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4874755/fblike-box-custom-css

Answer (score 0):

Find out which div class the element is, should be something like

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/tetrabyteuk" data-send="false"    data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>
```

the class is "fb-like"

so then write something like

```
.fb-like {
width: 200px;
padding: 3px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 5px;
font-size: 1em;
}
```

etc.

hope that helps :)

Comment: I can change the attribute of the entire unit that way, however it does not give me access to the inner elements...as facebook's code ultimately generates an iframe.

Comment: Well if it's inside an iframe, then mostly like it can't be done. The only solution would be to script your own button some how.